# Can a WebWorker function as a server?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, server, request, web-worker

I'm trying to create a clientside p2p connector in JS as part of a game-to-be, and there was a slight chance that I don't need another version of Node.js with a GUI, so I started to look around in Chrome's JS interface.

I found [the WebSocket Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) and [Xhr request API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), and I was hoping that it has a way to recieve updates from the server, but I didn't find a way to intercept any kind of messages from the internet, unless we connect to a server first.

So there is a workaround where the server just passes the messages between clients, but it's not p2p.

My question is:

- *Is there a way to recieve (special) http messages on the clientside?*
- *If not, is there a workaround that does not require large traffic?*

ps: I found that [GDevelop](https://gdevelop-app.com/) somehow implemented a p2p interface, but I don't want to revese engineer the site...

Comment: At the very least in order to facilitate the initial handshake in p2p you need a signaling server. There's no way to establish a peer connection without one.

Comment: Technically you can directly connect to a computer's IP adress, but I'm not sure if it's possibile in Chrome... (It's done with a special code, that contain the reuied informations to connect)

Comment: It seems you are looking for a [`RTCDataChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel) of [Web RTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API)

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you very much!